create Payment failed Card details not complete in Stripe ReactNative
I am using @stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.37.2" for payment. I want to make payment manually by enter card details in form and and pass parameter in createPaymentMethod and i am getting error create Payment failed Card details not complete.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StripeProvider, useStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
const MyComponent = () => {
 const stripe = useStripe();
 const [paymentMethodId, setPaymentMethodId] = useState(null);

 const onSubmitSteps = async () => {
   try {
            const { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'Card',
                billingDetails: {
                    name: 'Jenny Rosen',
                },
                card: {
                    number: '4242424242424242',
                    expMonth: 12,
                    expYear: 2025,
                    cvc: '123',
                },
            });

            if (error) {
                console.error('create Payment failed', error.message);
            } else if (paymentMethod) {
                setPaymentMethodId(paymentMethod.id);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error', 'An error occurred, please try again.');
        }
    };

    return (
        <StripeProvider publishableKey="YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY">
            {/* Your form and submit button */}
            <button onClick={onSubmitSteps}>Submit Payment</button>
        </StripeProvider>
    );
};


     
    return (
        <StripeProvider publishableKey="YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY">
            {/* Your form and submit button */}
            <button onClick={onSubmitSteps}>Submit Payment</button>
        </StripeProvider>
    );

};
export default MyComponent;
`
I need solution to create payment

You should use Stripe's UI elements that collect card details automatically for you instead of trying to pass raw card details in the API like this. Follow the end to end guide here: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native
